# Как лучше понять многопоточность в Qt или C++

Tags: многопоточность, qt, c++

Всегда как-то избегал или не приходилось, но и бывали моменты, где следовало сделать, а особо не знал, как, и, почитав пару мануалов, тоже не появилось особой тяги употреблять где-то. То есть, на первый взгляд, все просто, но после того как привык, что работает только в одном месте код (хоть и формально, конечно, в пределах того, что написал), как-то возникает много вопросов о параллельной работе. Так вот, это называется параллельным программированием? Есть ли то, что мастрид или даст хорошее понимание по-вашему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда-то мне все по полочкам расставила книга "Программирование под Windows для профессионалов" Джеффри Рихтера. Собственно, очень рекомендую. По-сути, познакомитесь с архитектурой Windows (что такое процесс, что такое поток, где какая память, как происходит ее маппинг, что вообще происходит в системе и прячется за обычными конструкциями языка, что такое объекты ядра и как они устроены и т.п.), но комплексное понимание того, как оно вообще бывает, сформируется.

http://wm-help.net/books-online/book/59464.html
Открыл, чтобы порекомендовать конкретные главы, но там с 3 по 25-ю главу все важно понимать. А это почти вся книга. :) Заодно нашел несколько разделов, которые решил перечитать. :)

Comment: @smallFish, спасибо, почитаю.

Answer (score 1):

Есть один способ понять - начать писать программы. Все остальное (кроме чтения документации, конечно) - пустая трата времени.

Comment: А сигналы со слотами в одном потоке с программой работают или для них отдельные потоки создаются?

Comment: Программа - это совокупность потоков и окружения. Поэтому Ваш вопрос некорректен.

Слоты и сигналы могут работать как в том одном потоке, так и в разных.

Comment: Когда я создаю свой сигнал и слот и при этом не создаю сам потоков, то они работают в том же потоке, что и остальной мой код? А сигналы и слоты определенные в Qt тоже будут работать в том же потоке, что и остальной код?

Comment: @xinakapu, все Ваши вопросы показывают, что Вам было бы очень полезно прочесть книгу, которую я выше порекомендовал. Собственно, в вопросах видно непонимание базиса, который там прекрасно расписан и дублировать который тут не имеет смысла.